# Выборка данных из БД напрямую, а не через REST API (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

Грузить данные с сайта на WordPress, используя REST API не совсем удобно.
Так получается что мы грузим всю запись - контент с html. А хотелось бы конкретнее, отдельно котлеты от мух так сказать.
Хотим попробовать делать запросы напрямую в базу данных. Возможно как то грузить их в Nodejs. Там обрабатывать и выдавать клиенту выборочно, а не целиком как в случае с аpi.

Реальна ли такая практика? Может кто поделится советом как правильнее, спасибо.

Comment: я думаю вам стоит лучше разобраться с REST API

Comment: И что вы там ожидаете, при прямых запросах в базу? То же самое и получите. Весь контент хранится в поле content записи в wp_posts.

Comment: @WPPunk через REST API я получаю JSON-файл, в котором из нужных полей есть только title и content. 
Я получаю лишь целый кусок. 
Хочу написать сайт-магазин, в котором будут товары, мне необходимо отдельно получать так называемые сущности: цену, медиа, текст, краткое описание и тому подобное. 

Плагин WooCommerce плодит названные сверху сущности в БД, что хорошо, только я смогу получить их одним запросом лишь целиком, а мне нужно, отправляя запрос, получить лишь, например, цену.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Верно, однако решил проблему при помощи WooCommerce. 
Обратите пожалуйста внимание на мой комментарий выше, расписал подробно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу, вы вообще неправильно делаете REST-запрос. title и content возвращаются для обычного поста, при запросе в WooCommerce таких полей в JSON-ответе нет. См., как правильно делать запрос в WooCommerce: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#retrieve-a-product

Здесь вам будут возвращены все характеристики товара, включая цену. Я считаю, не надо городить свой велосипед, строить свои REST-маршруты и т.д. Используйте стандартные запросы WooCommerce.

Comment: Понял-принял, благодарю за ответ! 
Можно ещё немного поинтересоваться? 
Если у меня в каталоге тысяча товаров, и мне нужно с каждого получить только изображения, мне всё равно их все грузить? 
Как долго будет обрабатываться данный запрос?

Comment: Если речь о том, что вам надо получить все изображения всех товаров, то одним запросом этого не сделать. Сначала надо будет получить id всех товаров, а потом в цикле, столько запросов, сколько товаров. Если всё это надо сделать быстро, придётся писать свой маршрут REST с обработчиком, который возвращает только изображения.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас услышал. Спасибо огромное)